# Findout Recently updated records in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a  table with 4 columns:

```
--------------------------------------
| ID (PK) |  Name  |  Addr  | Mobile |
--------------------------------------
```

Someone updated some records without ID. So how to find the recently updated records or updated Ids in SQL Server?

Comment: You need to have a `LastModifiedDateTime` property in your table, and you need to either set it from within an `AFTER UPDATE`  trigger, or from your application code. Or you can look at features like CDC (Change Data Capture) which are available in more recent versions of SQL Server